# Unexpected token export when deploying a MERN app to digitalocean

Tags: node.js, npm, syntax-error, digital-ocean, mern

I'm trying to deploy a MERN app to a digital ocean droplet. I have used nodemon and concurrently to run my app through "npm run dev". Everything works fine when running in my local machine, but when I git clone the project to the droplet and try to npm run dev to run the app on the remote server, I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I even removed the middleware where the error happens and tried to run again, but the error happened somewhere else in my code. I've stuck in this since yesterday. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @andrey Thank you very much for your answer. It solved my problem with export. Just to make sure, do I need to create a build folder by running "npm run build" in my frontend and add the build folder to the directory that contains my server.js (index.js) file manually? Because now I get errors relating to frontend start scripts and also the environment variables are undefined!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your Node version on the server. Most probably it's older and you're using ES6 exports.

If you got the right version that supports ES6, then you should make sure you've enabled that (as CommonJS is the default option). From [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system):

- Files ending in `.mjs`.
- Files ending in `.js` when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level "type" field with a value of `"module"`.
- Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval`, or piped to `node` via `STDIN`, with the flag `--input-type=module`.